# Use onvif to switch video encoding between H265 and H264

Tags: c++, h.264

I have obtained the H264 and H265 RTSP addresses of the webcam through onvif, now
I want to switch the video coding of the webcam through Onvif, may I ask what I should do?
Now, I use media2 SetVideoEncoderConfiguration to switch camera coding, function can be realized, but onvif gsoap in error, and not every support onvif webcam in this way can, what do I need to solve?

```
        if(ns9__SetVideoEncoderConfiguration.Configuration->Encoding==NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(piencoder,"H264") == 0)
            {
                 
               ns9__SetVideoEncoderConfiguration.Configuration>Encoding=soap_strdup(psoap,"H264");
            }
            else
            {
                ns9__SetVideoEncoderConfiguration.Configuration->Encoding=soap_strdup(psoap, "H265");
            }               
        }
    soap_wsse_add_UsernameTokenDigest(soap, "user", m_strUserName.c_str(), m_strPassword.c_str());
    int rv = soap_call___tr2__SetVideoEncoderConfiguration(soap, soap_endpoint, soap_action,
        tr2__SetVideoEncoderConfiguration, tr2__SetVideoEncoderConfigurationResponse);
    if (rv==0)
    {
        cout<<__FUNCTION__<<" success."<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<__FUNCTION__<<" failed,rv:"<<rv<<",soaperrorstr:"<<soaperrorstr(soap)<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

Media2SetVideoEncoderConfiguration failed,rv:-1,soaperrorstr: soap error: -1 ,faultcode: ,faultstring: